# Meteor Planifica/meteor-wizard

Tags: meteor

The documentation of Planifica/meteor-wizard tells that the SimpleSchema should be created as part of the template. I have all my Simple-Schema's as part of my collection and would like to keep it that way. Anyone knows if this can be done with Planifica/meteor-wizard?

Comment: More details or show us some code what you have so far?

Answer (score 2):

It should not matter where you define it. But in looking at the meteor-wizard docs it does look like you at least need a reference to it.

So instead of a helper that defines the schema, you just return a reference to it. So if you use the documentation example. Instead of:

```
Template.setupStepOne.schema = function() {
  return new SimpleSchema({
    ...
  });
}
```

You could use:

```
Template.setupStepOne.schema = CollectionName.Schema;
```

Just replace the CollectionName.Schema with a wherever you are storing your schema.

Comment: So I split my single schema (within the documents collection) in two schema's (equivalent to the wizard steps) and tried out your suggestion, but does not work. I also tried out the following with no success.
  Template.setupStepOne.helpers({
    schema: function() {
      return Documents.DocumentSchema1;
    }
  });
As a final step I then inserted the simpleschema's into the templates as mentioned in the documentation and it works in that case. Conclusion is that the wizard package does not support the definition of SimpleSchema's in the collection, but requires them in the Template helpers.

Answer (score 1):

```
Install first $ meteor add planifica:wizard

Please check bellow added small program. I think it is helpful for you.
<template name="setupWizard">
  {{> wizard id="setup-wizard" steps=steps}}
</template>

<template name="setupStepOne">
  {{#autoForm schema=schema doc=data id="setup-step-one-form"}}

    {{> afQuickField name="username"}}

    {{> afQuickField name="password"}}

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg pull-right">Next</button>

  {{/autoForm}}
</template>

<template name="setupStepTwo">
  {{#autoForm schema=schema doc=data id="setup-step-two-form"}}

    {{> afQuickField name="confirm"}}

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg pull-right">Submit</button>

  {{/autoForm}}
</template>


Then configure your schema's and steps

Template.setupWizard.steps = function() {
  return [{
    id: 'stepOne',
    title: 'Step 1. Your account',
    template: 'setupStepOne',
    formId: 'setup-step-one-form'
  }, {
    id: 'stepTwo',
    title: 'Step 2. Confirm',
    template: 'setupStepTwo',
    formId: 'setup-step-two-form',
    onSubmit: function(data, mergedData) {
      Accounts.createUser(mergedData, function(err) {
        if(!err) Router.go('/');
      });
    }
  }]
}

Template.setupStepOne.schema = function() {
  return new SimpleSchema({
    'username': {
      type: String,
      label: 'Username',
      min: 2,
      max: 30
    },
    'password': {
      type: String,
      label: 'Password',
      min: 6
    }
  });
}

Template.setupStepTwo.schema = function() {
  return new SimpleSchema({
    'password': {
      type: Boolean,
      label: 'Confirm your registration'
    }
  });
}
```